# HTML parsing individual tables/not all data being parsed?

Tags: windows-phone-8, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm rather new when it comes to Windows Phone 8 development and I've been toying around with a few things as part of the application I'm developing.

Right now I'm trying to parse information from a  website such as the RuneScape 07 High Scores - http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=zezima

I'm using HTML Agility Pack and I'm able to parse *some* data (down to Woodcutting), but anything passed that doesn't appear? (Is that down to the size of my ListBox?)

Ideally, I'd like to be able to parse the table information individually rather than in one block like so:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HtmlWeb.LoadAsync("http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=zezima", DownLoadCompleted);
    }

    void DownLoadCompleted(object sender, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e)
    {
        if(e.Error == null)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = e.Document;
            if (doc != null)
            {
                var result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='contentHiscores']");
               foreach (var htmlNode in result)
               {
                   lBox.Items.Add(htmlNode.InnerText);
               }
            }
        }
```

But if I try and access an individual table such as this one using

```
var result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='contentHiscores']/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]");
```

I get a NullReferenceException.

Is this possible or am I doing something exceptionally wrong?

Comment: Is it result that's null or the InnerText attribute?

Comment: It's result that is null, when it comes to the foreach it breaks when trying to access specific points.

Comment: If you break it down a bit, removing each sub query as you go, when you you get a non-null result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably relied on a developper tools such as FireBug or Chrome, etc... to determine the XPATH for the nodes you're after.

You can' really do this as the XPATH given by such tools correspond to the in memory HTML DOM while the Html Agility Pack only knows about the raw HTML sent back by the server.

What you need to do is look at what's sent back (or just do a view source). You'll see there is no TBODY element for example. So you want to find anything discriminant, and use [XPATH axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp) for example.

Here is a code that seems to work:

```
// get all TD nodes with ALIGN attribute set to left
foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='contentHiscores']//td[@align='left']"))
{
    var item = lBox.Items.Add(node.InnerText.Trim());
    // use an 'XPATH axe': get all sibling TD nodes with ALIGN attribute set to 'right'
    foreach (var sibling in node.SelectNodes("following-sibling::td[@align='right']"))
    {
        item.SubItems.Add(sibling.InnerText.Trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's helped me immensely and I now have a greater understanding! :)

One last thing at the risk of sounding silly -- if I was to implement that as is I get a 

`Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable` error regarding the var item = lbox.x.x. 

Is this to do with my `void DownLoadCompleted` call back, or another  reason? We haven't really covered vars yet on my course so I'm probably ahead of myself. :) @SimonMourier

Comment: @Optimistic - Oh that was just for the sample purpose. This code would work on Windorms forms (and add one item + a bunch of sub items), but on your platform it means the Add returns nothing.